# How I can proper handle the SPI read register function? I am facing a debug error

Tags: embedded, protocols, stm32, spi, bare-metal

I am using SPI communication protocol in order to communicate my board with the NRF. I have the nucleo stm32l053r8 board. I am working in stmcubeide and trying to find a problem in dubbing which is based on spi_read function. All am doing is to read from the NRF  the reset values of its registers for example CONFIG,EN_AA, STATUS and etc. I am using  the debugger for that using breakpoints to see if the values which  spi_read function returns are proper. **The problem** is that it returns only the first value right and after that despite that I want to read the EN_AA register it continues to send me back the CONFIG value.

All of the other functions are working fine.

spi_read function:

```
    uint8_t res=0;

    SPI1->DR=0xff;
    while(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_BSY));
    while(!READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_RXNE));
    res = SPI1->DR;


    while(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_RXNE)==1)
    {
        READ_REG(SPI1->DR);
    }
    while(!(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_TXE)));
    while(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_BSY));


    SPI1->DR = reg;

    while(!(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_RXNE)));

    READ_REG(SPI1->DR);
    while(!(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_TXE)));
    while(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_BSY));
    SPI1->DR = 0xff;
    while(!(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_RXNE))); // Wait until there is some data into the buffer before start reading.
    res = SPI1->DR;
    while(!(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_TXE)));
    while(READ_BIT(SPI1->SR,SPI_SR_BSY));

    return res;
and the main function which is for testing the spi read :

    uint8_t res_1=0;

    init_rcc(); // clock configurations
    gpio_configure(); 
    spi_configure();

    while(1){

        for (uint8_t i=0;i<4;i++){ // I want to read the first 4 register values
            CS_enable();
            res_1 = SPI_read(CONFIG+i); starting from CONFIG and keep going. 
            CS_disable();
        }

    }
}
```

If I run the it for one time using a break point in the CS_enable(); when spi_read() works for first time it returns the proper value with is 8 after that despite that in the loop with the command res_1 = SPI_read(CONFIG+i); after the second try of the spi_read goes another register it still return 8 which is for register CONFIG. What I am missing in the spi_read steps?

Answer (score 0):

Your writing and reading from DR is invalid.

you need to

```
*(uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR = reg;
```

```
res = *(uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR;
```

Why? Because this micro has FIFO and you access the register using 32bit write which FIFO interprets as 2 bytes.

Your `BSY` flag testing is not needed. `BSY` flag is used if you want to disable `SPI` or to reconfigure DMA (to be sure that all data was sent)./

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply but it stills not changing the value when the loop in main wants to read another registers.

Comment: Is it a good idea to clear the DR register after every loop ?